# Syntax errors with parsing CSV file with headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using `ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux]` where I am trying to test a script. The following does not work as expected

```
CSV.foreach(tscm_hosts_file, headers: tscm_hosts_file_col_headers) do |row|
  catch :bad_data do
    tscm_hosts_file_col_headers.each do |header|
      throw :bad_data if row[header].nil?
    end
.
.....
```

And error received is

```
[root@fmsprdchef001 ~]# ./generate_autoreg_output.rb
./generate_autoreg_output.rb:75: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
...each(tscm_hosts_file, headers: tscm_hosts_file_col_headers) ...
```

I think this is the because of the ruby version I am using. Can someone tell which RUby version supports this syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move from

```
CSV.foreach(tscm_hosts_file, headers: tscm_hosts_file_col_headers)
```

to

```
CSV.foreach(tscm_hosts_file, :headers => tscm_hosts_file_col_headers)
```

The new hash syntax for symbols has been introduced in Ruby 1.9

Comment: so to use the existing script I should move to `1.9` ?

Comment: Yes, for that syntax you need at least ruby 1.9. Is that script a gem, just a file you have or what?

Comment: Its just a .rb file

Comment: You can either use ruby 1.9 or fix that file to the old syntax. But other changes could be needed.

Comment: @aaj if changing ruby versions is an option you should do it even 1.9 has been out of support for quite some time